# How to add period selector in AmSerialChart?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am new to [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com/). Does anyone know how to add period selector in AmSerialChart.

I have tried this:

```
var periodSelector = new AmCharts.PeriodSelector();
            periodSelector.position = "left";
            periodSelector.periods = [{
                period: "DD",
                count: 10,
                label: "10 days"
            }, {
                period: "MM",
                selected: true,
                count: 1,
                label: "1 month"
            }, {
                period: "YYYY",
                count: 1,
                label: "1 year"
            }, {
                period: "YTD",
                label: "YTD"
            }, {
                period: "MAX",
                label: "MAX"
            }];
            chart.periodSelector = periodSelector;
```

It doesn't create any change.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Period Selector](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/PeriodSelector) is an exclusive feature of the JavaScript Stock Chart, and is not available in regular serial charts.

There are two ways to go about it:

1) Implement your own external HTML controls to select periods. Then use chart's [`zoomToDates()`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#zoomToDates) method to set specific time range.

OR

2) Switch to [Stock Char](http://www.amcharts.com/stock-chart/)t and get Period Selector out-of-the-box. Stock Chart can be configured to look exactly like Serial chart. The biggest difference is that you will need to define panels (in your case just one) as well as data sets (again just one).

If you could update your question with the code and data you have so far, I could update mine with a similar Stock Chart.